# Xamarin: How to read the developer guide and get GPS coordinates

Tags: c#, gps

I am pretty sure, this is a noob think to ask but here goes:

Im Writing on a small app, that for now is supposed to return a string with gps coordinates. This is as far as i got:

```
public string GiveGpsLocation()
{
    string StringWithCoordinates = "NULL";




    return StringWithCoordinates;
```

So, as you see - Im pretty helpless atm ;)

Anyway, I came across this little website: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Locations.Location/

There, under public methodes i found this bit:
static
    Convert(Double, Format) : String

```
Converts a coordinate to a String representation.
```

Now, i am very new to c# and all ( came form pascal...) and i was just wondering over how to use this. I basically is what I need, now I need to implement this into my code. How would I start? Im sorry, if this is already TOO easy, but im really stuck :(

Thanks a hundret :)

Answer (score 3):

This link provides a full explanation on how to get gps cordnitates in a bit easier way then going through the api.
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/